# Executing a Root access based commands on Android application

Tags: android, c, adb

I basically want to start a process which resides in `/system/bin/...` from the Application `java` command.
I tried all types of `Runtime.process.exec()` options
Tried the `su` and `ouputStream` combination as well, but nothing is able to start the application.
I am using the code in device and emulators, no luck in both.
I am able to run the same commands from ADB Shell successfully (as it has root permissions).

The device is rooted, I am able to see the # when I use adb to debug my device and it also can go into su via adb.
based on my searching I found that (after doing ps from adb shell)
I am able to run any command with lrwz--x--x permission such as (ls->toolbox, ps->toolbox) from the application layer but I am not able to execute any other commands which are not linked to the toolbox.

This doesn't execute `ls`:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os=new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("ls \n");
os.flush();
```

But this does execute `ls`:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
```

I would really appreciate if I can get any help on this here! I am posting this after doing lots of research.

Comment: What error messages or error codes or exceptions do you get when trying to execute programs?

Comment: Did you verify in your SuperUser app that said app is allowed to access 'su'. I pretty sure SuperUser keeps a list of apps to blacklist, maybe you blacklisted it at some point

Comment: @sarnold I don't get any exception or errors, it just dosent execute if I give 
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  DataOutputStream os=new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
  os.writeBytes("ls \n");
  os.flush();
the ls dosent get execueted...however 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
executes without any problem, I get to read data using a standard input stream.

Comment: @user931366 how do I check  the blacklist? where are they listed?

Comment: I found that the operations/permissions of su again depends on how/who routed the phone. which means the su application's capabilities, the phone decides execute the required application in super user mode during runtime dependingly, if I am rite then how am I supposed to move ahead with this?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than sending `ls \n` to the `su` command's standard input, try running:

```
su -c ls
```

The `-c` option to `su(1)` asks it to run a command with elevated privileges rather than starting an interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a shell script file(eg: init.sh) and write following commands in it:

su

reboot

Now try executing this shell script by
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh init.sh");

If this restarted your droid then you can write your required code in init.sh file & run it.

Comment: try out example from this [link](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html)

It may help you to figure out what actually is going wrong.